# flotr display data series name when mouse hovers over line

Tags: javascript, flot, flotr

I'm using flotr to graph 90 data sets. On average, only two of the 90 sets of data will actually produce a graphable line. The other 88 or so will have y values so low that they will barely peak above the x axis. Here is an example...

[image]

My problem is that I don't know what data set those two lines are.  I could make a legend, but that legend would be huge because there are about 90 data sets.  So I was wondering if flotr has a function to label these data sets when the mouse hovers over graphed data for that data set.  Does such a function exist?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I found my answer.  I saw this example...

http://phenxdesign.net/projects/flotr/examples/prototype/mouse-tracking.html

This one uses tracking support but it only shows the x and y values.  I saw this line....

```
trackFormatter: function(obj){ return 'x = ' + obj.x +', y = ' + obj.y; }
```

and changed it to this...

```
trackFormatter: function(obj){ return 'x = ' + obj.x +', y = ' + obj.y  +', Data Series = ' + obj.series.label; }
```

Then I specified a data label for each data set and passed them to Flotr.draw in an associative array.  I did this by changing this...

```
[dataset1, dataset2]
```

to this...

```
[{data:dataset1,label:'label_for_dataset1'}, {data:dataset2,label:'label_for_dataset2'}]
```

Below is an example of the changes I made.  Now the mouse hover shows x and y values and whatever data label you enter.

**Before:**

```
var dataset1 = [[100, 4.09453e-29], [99, 1.41672e-28],...... ];
var dataset2 = [[100, 9.48582e-19], [99, 1.88215e-18],...... ];

var f = Flotr.draw(
        $('container'), 
        [dataset1, dataset2],
        {
            mouse:{
                track: true,
                lineColor: 'purple',
                relative: true,
                position: 'ne',
                sensibility: 1, // => The smaller this value, the more precise you've to point
                trackDecimals: 2,
                trackFormatter: function(obj){ return 'x = ' + obj.x +', y = ' + obj.y; }
            },
            crosshair:{
                mode: 'xy'
            }
        }
    );
```

**After:**

```
var dataset1 = [[100, 4.09453e-29], [99, 1.41672e-28],...... ];
var dataset2 = [[100, 9.48582e-19], [99, 1.88215e-18],...... ];

var f = Flotr.draw(
        $('container'), 
        [{data:dataset1,label:'enter_label_for_dataset1_here'}, {data:dataset2,label:'enter_label_for_dataset2_here'}],
        {
            mouse:{
                track: true,
                lineColor: 'purple',
                relative: true,
                position: 'ne',
                sensibility: 1, // => The smaller this value, the more precise you've to point
                trackDecimals: 2,
                trackFormatter: function(obj){ return 'x = ' + obj.x +', y = ' + obj.y  +', Data Series = ' + obj.series.label; }
            },
            crosshair:{
                mode: 'xy'
            }
        }
    );
```